# Writing csv in Python 3

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I'm a extremely beginner in Python and all I want to do is to delete space in some sells in the table.
But because of the error, I cannot write csv.
I've already checked several related posts in stackoverflow, but still couldn't correct my cord.

## Error

line 27, in  
csvWriter.writerow(corrected) 
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

## Code

```
import csv

# Read CSV
csvfile = '/Users/Study/Data/WGI/forPython.csv'
f = open(csvfile, 'r', newline='')
data = csv.reader(f)

# 
g = open('/Users/Study/Data/WGI/WGI_Data_Renamed_Python.csv', 'ab')
csvWriter = csv.writer(g)

# 
corrected = []

count = 0

# 
for row in data:
    corrected.append([])             
    corrected[count] = str.rstrip(row[0])
    count = count + 1

print(corrected)

# 
csvWriter.writerow(corrected)
g.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, `csv.writer` in Python 3 [*doesn't support binary output streams*](http://grokbase.com/t/python/python-bugs-list/111me0k9fm/issue10954-no-warning-for-csv-writer-api-change). This isn't mentioned in the documentation, and worse, it's *backwards* from the Python 2 recommendation of always opening the underlying files with `b`.

Luckily for you, the fix is easy: just open the file in text mode instead of binary. The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) also recommend that you specify `newline=''` when opening the file, so you might as well do that too.

```
g = open('/Users/Study/Data/WGI/WGI_Data_Renamed_Python.csv', 'a', newline='')
csvWriter = csv.writer(g)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your post, Henry! But I still got the same error even if I modified the line you've mentioned.

Comment: @user51966 Python 3 seems to have silently dropped support for binary output streams in the csv writers. I'd updated my answer accordingly; take a look and see if it helps!